# Using uwsgi server as socketio client

Tags: python, nginx, flask, socket.io, uwsgi

I have a Flask app and inside it I have a socket io client that emits events to a node.js server when it receives http requests, in development mode it was working fine but when I deploy it with uwsgi and nginx I can't emit events, it connects to the node.js server and after a while it disconnects, but never emit event, how do I solve this?